# Autotest: "Could not run tests". But nothing in the log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, autotest, zentest

Autotest broke with `rspec-rails 2.2.1` update. Now I can't get it working again.. .even after rolling back to `rspec-rais 2.2.0`.

Only info I'm able to find is a Growl popup saying "**App: Could not run tests**". Nothing is being written to `log/test.log`.

this is output in console:

```
/Users/meltemi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby -I.:lib:test -rubygems -e "%w[test/unit test/test_helper.rb].each { |f| require f }" | unit_diff -u
Loaded suite -e
Started

Finished in 0.003428 seconds.


0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Test run options: --seed 38767
```

Any ideas where to start troubleshooting this? I'd look in an `autotest.log`...if i could find one!?!

**Edit:** tried running autotest with `autotest -v` and get a looong list of "**No tests matched...**" in the console (20± examples below):

```
...
No tests matched .git/objects/fe/41f5cc24d667635c46a533fd09bf7bb514e032
No tests matched .git/objects/fe/4577696b2811818fe7439990be0d2f65a892c5
No tests matched .git/objects/fe/e16b09c5e782035a347ed9b257ff9b2b3fa173
No tests matched .git/refs/heads/MenuModel
No tests matched .git/refs/heads/master
No tests matched .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
No tests matched .git/refs/tags/v0.0.1
No tests matched .git/refs/tags/v0.0.1.1
No tests matched .gitignore
No tests matched .rspec
No tests matched Capfile
No tests matched Gemfile
No tests matched Gemfile.lock
No tests matched README
No tests matched Rakefile
No tests matched app/helpers/application_helper.rb
No tests matched autotest/discover.rb
No tests matched config/application.rb
No tests matched config/boot.rb
No tests matched config/database.yml
No tests matched config/deploy.rb
No tests matched config/environment.rb
...
```

here's the config (`~/.autotest`):

```
# ~/.autotest
# Include plugins
require 'autotest/fsevent'
require 'autotest/growl'

# ./.autotest
# exceptions (files to ignore) 
# mappings (which files to specifically monitor for changes)
Autotest.add_hook(:initialize) {|at|
  at.add_exception %r{^\.git}  # ignore Version Control System
  at.add_exception %r{^./tmp}  # ignore temp files, lest autotest will run again, and again...
  #  at.clear_mappings         # take out the default (test/test*rb)
  at.add_mapping(%r{^lib/.*\.rb$}) {|f, _|
    Dir['spec/**/*.rb']
  }
  nil
}
```

Comment: Does this work?: `autotest -s rspec2`

Comment: **yes!!!** please put this into an answer so I can give you credit. also, if possible, tell me what's different so I can understand why simply typing `autotest` no longer works for me...  I can't seem to find a manpage for `autotest`..so no idea what `-s rspec2` has done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`autotest -s rspec2` tells autotest to use the "rspec2" style, which will make it look for spec files and run the examples therein.

This is just a workaround though. Autotest is supposed to discover the specs based on the entries in your project's `./autotest/discover.rb`. And as you found, a recent code update broke the autodiscovery. I ran into this myself and was unable to track down the source.